# Error in tau.hat$predictions + 1.96 * sigma.hat : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, rstudio

```
`library(causalTree)`
`library(gradient.forest)`
`library(ggplot2)`
```

## Generate sample data

```
`n = 2000`
`p = 10`
`X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)`
`W = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)`
`tau_x = pmax(X[,1], 0)`
`Y =  tau_x * W + X[,2] + pmin(X[,3], 0) + rnorm(n)`
```

## construct X.test

```
`X.test = matrix(0, 101, p)`
`X.test[,1] = seq(-2, 2, length.out = 101)`
```

## Estimate

```
`tau.forest = causal.forest(X, Y, W, num.trees = 1000)`
```

## Do prediction

```
`tau.hat = predict(tau.forest, X.test, estimate.variance = TRUE)`
`sigma.hat = sqrt(tau.hat$variance.estimates)
```

## graph the line and standard errors

```
`ylim = range(tau.hat$predictions + 1.96 * sigma.hat, tau.hat$predictions - 1.96 * sigma.hat)`
`plot(X.test[,1], tau.hat$predictions, ylim = ylim, xlab = "x", ylab = "tau", type = "l")`
`lines(X.test[,1], tau.hat$predictions + 1.96 * sigma.hat, col = 1, lty = 2)`
`lines(X.test[,1], tau.hat$predictions - 1.96 * sigma.hat, col = 1, lty = 2)`
`lines(X.test[,1], pmax(0, X.test[,1]), col = 2, lty = 1)`
```

I am trying to plot a gradient forest graph using a randomly generated data. When I try to run the code in Rstudio, the following error appeared:

Error in tau.hat$predictions + 1.96 * sigma.hat : non-conformable arrays

when i try to run this specific line of code:

```
`ylim = range(tau.hat$predictions + 1.96 * sigma.hat, tau.hat$predictions - 1.96 * sigma.hat)`
```

I am really confused as to why this occurred, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize for the bad formatting and wording, this is my 2nd time posting questions.

Comment: Please remove all those backticks from your code.

Comment: Have you checked the structure of `tau.hat$predictions` and `sigma.hat`?